# Monitor setup wrong after first boot after switching from windows

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-mate, nvidia-geforce

I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and Windows 10.
When I switch from Windows to Ubuntu, on the first boot, my triple-monitor setup gets messed up. Only the middle monitor (the only one used on Windows) is active, but it seems all three desktops are compressed on it, or at least the MATE-bars. Also the whole Desktop becomes extremely laggy, about half a second delay on any action.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

My current solution is to just reboot Ubuntu, which fixes the setup and everything is back the way it should be.

I use a GTX 1080Ti and suspected the Nvidia Driver as the source, but an update to the newest version made no difference.

Sadly I'm not overly familiar with the inner workings of Ubuntu, yet, so I'm kind of stuck and don't know where to contiune.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hint, for those finding it later.

Updating my BIOS seems to have fixed the problem. But I'm not 100% sure of this, so take this with a grain of salt.